# how to check if notification is active in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I get some data Jsonarray from server every 60 seconds  and I use jsonarray  to build notification in for-loop;
However I don't know how to know if notification is active than pass next one to build the notification
is there any way to do it ?

Comment: you can use the `NotificationManager.getActiveNotifications()` method it returns a list of active notifications that are posted by your app and are not canceled by your app or dismissed by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NotificationManager can keep track of it for you.

> getActiveNotifications:
>   added in API level 23
>   StatusBarNotification[] getActiveNotifications ()
>   Recover a list of active notifications: ones that have been posted by the calling app that have not yet been dismissed by the user or cancel(String, int)ed by the app. Each notification is embedded in a StatusBarNotification object, including the original tag and id supplied to notify() (via getTag() and getId()) as well as a copy of the original Notification object (via getNotification()).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getActiveNotifications()